# Get weight in android

Tags: android

I am new Android development, and I have a question about get width of View in Android.
I set weight of view = 1

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSTT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And I try to find way to get width of this in java code. How should I do?
Sorry about my English.

Comment: Documenation:[getWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth())

Comment: Thanks Sagar Pilkhwal, but when i call getWidth(), it return 0.

Comment: `layout_weight` doesn't have a unit. That is, remove the `dp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TextView` will get a width at the moment it is drawn. Before that moment, it is not clear what its actual width will be (because of many different screen sizes).
You can add an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the viewTreeObserver to be notified when it is drawn.
You can perform getWidth() in the listener and it should not be 0 anymore.

Add an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` like so

```
final TextView tvSTTtextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSTT);
    textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View view, View view2) {
            int width = tvSTTtextView.getWidth(); //width should not be 0
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  //Here you can get the width! use `getWidth()`
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the view's layout params and cast it to TableLayout.LayoutParams, one you have it you can access to the view weight

```
((TableLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).weight;// this is the weight
```